# Why we have to parse date before inserting in DB?

Tags: mysql, parsing

Okay, so I was working on a project and I encountered with an error 'unexpected data'. I searched everywhere but I couldn't understand what was going wrong, and then I saw an answer on Stack Overflow that you have to parse date before inserting in database. I parsed date and it worked. I want to know why we have to parse date before entering in database if date is fetched from an API?

Comment: The MySQL database needs the date in format Y-m-d format. If the API provides a other format you have to format the date

Comment: If you posted some code or the date as it was formatted when it came from your API, you would get much more precise answers. Your question is very vague.

Comment: @C14L sorry If my formatting is not correct, I'm just asking a general question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, primarily due to type incompatibility between return type from your API and that which your DB system supports. You may use an ORM like Hibernate so it takes care of that. Research and find out how to use. Anyways, which type did you parse your date object from API to?

Comment: I fetched data from magento, I'm using Laravel framework and I parsed date with Carbon.